# Convert Raw SMBios table to human readable text with batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, bios

The purpose of the project is to *understand* how to read the data and, if possible, filter a specific value. I would like to **avoid using 3rd party** tools.

To read out the raw bios data I use wmic:
`wmic /Namespace:\\root\WMI Path MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables Get SMBiosData`

This generates a decimal CSV code of "to be interpreted values" and ASCII decimal encoded strings:
 `{0, 26, 0, 0, 1, 2, ... }` *plus* some strange preceding content. (?!)

##### The main problem I have right now is to understand the row start, end sequence:

If I look at the cheatsheets I got the problem of hex/byte codes vs decimal numbers. Second the decimals are terminated at two indexes `0, 26` instead of what I expect are four indexes like `[TYPE], [LENGTH], [HANDLE], 00Termination`.
Additional it would be nice to know where the strange preceding content comes from.

What I got so far:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

REM Use agrument 1 to start batch a new window (not in the same command prompt)
IF "%~1" == "" START "RawSMBios Decode" %comspec% /D /A /C ""%~F0" W" & EXIT /B

ENDLOCAL
SET CurrentFolder=%CD%
CD /D "%temp%"

CHCP 1252>NUL

REM CHARTABLE - ASCII printable chars with decimal index
SET "CHARTABLE[32]= "
SET "CHARTABLE[33]=!"
SET "CHARTABLE[34]="""
REM Stack overflow code has a problem with escaped double quote so remove one...
SET "CHARTABLE[34]=%CHARTABLE[34]:~-1%"
SET "CHARTABLE[35]=#"
SET "CHARTABLE[36]=$"
SET "CHARTABLE[37]=%%"
SET "CHARTABLE[38]=&"
SET "CHARTABLE[39]='"
SET "CHARTABLE[40]=("
SET "CHARTABLE[41]=)"
SET "CHARTABLE[42]=*"
SET "CHARTABLE[43]=+"
SET "CHARTABLE[44]=,"
SET "CHARTABLE[45]=-"
SET "CHARTABLE[46]=."
SET "CHARTABLE[47]=/"
SET "CHARTABLE[48]=0"
SET "CHARTABLE[49]=1"
SET "CHARTABLE[50]=2"
SET "CHARTABLE[51]=3"
SET "CHARTABLE[52]=4"
SET "CHARTABLE[53]=5"
SET "CHARTABLE[54]=6"
SET "CHARTABLE[55]=7"
SET "CHARTABLE[56]=8"
SET "CHARTABLE[57]=9"
SET "CHARTABLE[58]=:"
SET "CHARTABLE[59]=;"
SET "CHARTABLE[60]=<"
SET "CHARTABLE[61]=="
SET "CHARTABLE[62]=>"
SET "CHARTABLE[63]=?"
SET "CHARTABLE[64]=@"
SET "CHARTABLE[65]=A"
SET "CHARTABLE[66]=B"
SET "CHARTABLE[67]=C"
SET "CHARTABLE[68]=D"
SET "CHARTABLE[69]=E"
SET "CHARTABLE[70]=F"
SET "CHARTABLE[71]=G"
SET "CHARTABLE[72]=H"
SET "CHARTABLE[73]=I"
SET "CHARTABLE[74]=J"
SET "CHARTABLE[75]=K"
SET "CHARTABLE[76]=L"
SET "CHARTABLE[77]=M"
SET "CHARTABLE[78]=N"
SET "CHARTABLE[79]=O"
SET "CHARTABLE[80]=P"
SET "CHARTABLE[81]=Q"
SET "CHARTABLE[82]=R"
SET "CHARTABLE[83]=S"
SET "CHARTABLE[84]=T"
SET "CHARTABLE[85]=U"
SET "CHARTABLE[86]=V"
SET "CHARTABLE[87]=W"
SET "CHARTABLE[88]=X"
SET "CHARTABLE[89]=Y"
SET "CHARTABLE[90]=Z"
SET "CHARTABLE[91]=["
SET "CHARTABLE[92]=\"
SET "CHARTABLE[93]=]"
SET "CHARTABLE[94]=^"
SET "CHARTABLE[95]=_"
SET "CHARTABLE[96]=`"
SET "CHARTABLE[97]=a"
SET "CHARTABLE[98]=b"
SET "CHARTABLE[99]=c"
SET "CHARTABLE[100]=d"
SET "CHARTABLE[101]=e"
SET "CHARTABLE[102]=f"
SET "CHARTABLE[103]=g"
SET "CHARTABLE[104]=h"
SET "CHARTABLE[105]=i"
SET "CHARTABLE[106]=j"
SET "CHARTABLE[107]=k"
SET "CHARTABLE[108]=l"
SET "CHARTABLE[109]=m"
SET "CHARTABLE[110]=n"
SET "CHARTABLE[111]=o"
SET "CHARTABLE[112]=p"
SET "CHARTABLE[113]=q"
SET "CHARTABLE[114]=r"
SET "CHARTABLE[115]=s"
SET "CHARTABLE[116]=t"
SET "CHARTABLE[117]=u"
SET "CHARTABLE[118]=v"
SET "CHARTABLE[119]=w"
SET "CHARTABLE[120]=x"
SET "CHARTABLE[121]=y"
SET "CHARTABLE[122]=z"
SET "CHARTABLE[123]={"
SET "CHARTABLE[124]=|"
SET "CHARTABLE[125]=}"
SET "CHARTABLE[126]=~"
REM Type 126 is used for disabled entries ?
SET "CHARTABLE[127]=" & REM Delete = Beep / end-of-table marker...

REM -> Creating a Line Feed variable (the blank line is required!)
SET CHARTABLE[0A]=^

<NUL
REM <- The above blank line is required!

REM List of SMBIOS codes
SET "BIOSSPEC[0]= BIOS "
SET "BIOSSPEC[1]= System "
SET "BIOSSPEC[2]= Baseboard "
SET "BIOSSPEC[3]= Chassis "
SET "BIOSSPEC[4]= Processor "
SET "BIOSSPEC[5]= Memory Controller "
SET "BIOSSPEC[6]= Memory Module "
SET "BIOSSPEC[7]= Cache "
SET "BIOSSPEC[8]= Port Connector "
SET "BIOSSPEC[9]= System Slots "
SET "BIOSSPEC[10]= On Board Devices "
SET "BIOSSPEC[11]= OEM Strings "
SET "BIOSSPEC[12]= System Configuration Options "
SET "BIOSSPEC[13]= BIOS Language "
SET "BIOSSPEC[14]= Group Associations "
SET "BIOSSPEC[15]= System Event Log "
SET "BIOSSPEC[16]= Physical Memory Array "
SET "BIOSSPEC[17]= Memory Device "
SET "BIOSSPEC[18]= 32-bit Memory Error "
SET "BIOSSPEC[19]= Memory Array Mapped Address "
SET "BIOSSPEC[20]= Memory Device Mapped Address "
SET "BIOSSPEC[21]= Built-in Pointing Device "
SET "BIOSSPEC[22]= Portable Battery "
SET "BIOSSPEC[23]= System Reset "
SET "BIOSSPEC[24]= Hardware Security "
SET "BIOSSPEC[25]= System Power Controls "
SET "BIOSSPEC[26]= Voltage Probe "
SET "BIOSSPEC[27]= Cooling Device "
SET "BIOSSPEC[28]= Temperature Probe "
SET "BIOSSPEC[29]= Electrical Current Probe "
SET "BIOSSPEC[30]= Out-of-band Remote Access "
SET "BIOSSPEC[31]= Boot Integrity Services "
SET "BIOSSPEC[32]= System Boot "
SET "BIOSSPEC[33]= 64-bit Memory Error "
SET "BIOSSPEC[34]= Management Device "
SET "BIOSSPEC[35]= Management Device Component "
SET "BIOSSPEC[36]= Management Device Threshold Data "
SET "BIOSSPEC[37]= Memory Channel "
SET "BIOSSPEC[38]= IPMI Device "
SET "BIOSSPEC[39]= Power Supply "
SET "BIOSSPEC[40]= Additional Information "
SET "BIOSSPEC[41]= Onboard Devices Extended Information "
SET "BIOSSPEC[42]= Management Controller Host Interface "


REM Activate extensions
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "CHARTABLE[0A]=!CHARTABLE[0A]:~0,1!"

REM Generate temp file / somehow for loop fails because of strange characters before { ... } ?
FOR %%A IN ("%~nx0") DO SET TempNamePrefix=%%~nA
SET "tmpFile=%temp%\%TempNamePrefix%%random%.tmp"

REM Get RAW SMBIOS data
wmic /Namespace:\\root\WMI Path MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables Get SMBiosData > "%tmpFile%"
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=* delims=" %%X IN (`find "," "%tmpFile%"`) DO SET "DATA=%%X"

REM TYPE "%tmpFile%"
REM PAUSE

REM Delete temp file
DEL /F /Q "%tmpFile%" >NUL 2>NUL

IF "!DATA!" == "" ECHO/No data. & GOTO :Exit

REM Remove { }
SET "DATA=!DATA:~1,-1!"
REM Remove spaces
SET "DATA=!DATA: =!"

REM Generate a numeric array to access data in a better way.
SET /A COUNTER=-1
:LOOP
FOR /F "usebackq delims=," %%X IN ('!DATA!') DO (
   SET /A COUNTER+=1
   SET "DATA[!COUNTER!]=%%X"
   SET "DATA=!DATA:*%%X=!"
   GOTO :LOOP
)
SET DATA=

REM Convert to human readable text
SET FLAG_A=0
REM Structure is 0 -> Type / 1 -> Length / 2 -> Handle / XXX -> Data ... ?
SET /A FLAG_L=0
FOR /L %%I IN (0,1,!COUNTER!) DO (
   SET /A PREV=%%I - 1
   SET /A NEXT=%%I + 1
   FOR /F "usebackq" %%P IN ('!PREV!') DO FOR /F "usebackq" %%N IN ('!NEXT!') DO FOR /F "usebackq" %%C IN ('!DATA[%%I]!') DO (
      IF "!FLAG_L!" == "0" (
         CALL :TryParseC "%%C" 1 Result
         IF "!Result:~-1!" == " " SET "Result=!Result:~0,-1!"
         SET "DATA=!DATA!!Result!: "
         SET /A FLAG_L+=1
      ) ELSE IF "!FLAG_L!" == "1" (
         SET /A FLAG_L+=1
      ) ELSE IF "!FLAG_L!" == "2" (
         SET /A FLAG_L+=1
      ) ELSE (
         IF "!DATA[%%I]!" == "0" (
            IF "!DATA[%%N]!" == "0" (
               SET FLAG_A=1
            ) ELSE IF "!DATA[%%P]!" == "0" (
               SET "DATA=!DATA!!CHARTABLE[0A]!" & REM 00 indicates structure end, lf instead.
               SET /A FLAG_L=0
            )
         ) ELSE (
            SET FLAG_A=0
         )
         IF "!FLAG_A!" == "0" (
            CALL :TryParseC "%%C" 0 Result
            SET "DATA=!DATA!!Result!"
         )
      )
   )
)
SET "DATA=!DATA:  = !"
GOTO :END

REM Try to understand what value should be the right one
REM CALL :TryParseC "Number" Order ReturnVar
:TryParseC
SET TARGETA=CHARTABLE
SET TARGETB=BIOSSPEC
IF "%~2" == "1" (
   SET TARGETA=BIOSSPEC
   SET TARGETB=CHARTABLE
)
IF DEFINED %TARGETA%[%~1] (
   SET "%~3=!%TARGETA%[%~1]!"
) ELSE IF DEFINED %TARGETB%[%~1] (
   SET "%~3=!%TARGETB%[%~1]!"
) ELSE (
   SET "%~3= %~1"
)
EXIT /B

:END
REM Finally beep two times to herald the result ;)
ECHO/!CHARTABLE[127]!
ECHO/ ---------------------------------------------------
ECHO/ --              R  E  S  U  L  T                 --
ECHO/ ---------------------------------------------------
ECHO/!DATA!
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 800 >NUL
ECHO/!CHARTABLE[127]!
:Exit
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
CD /D "%CurrentFolder%"
```

At the moment the output is quite a massacre. The strings are at least displayed correctly (more or less).

##### I use the following collection of references:

- https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios
- https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/smbios-demystified/#SMBIOS
- https://github.com/nima/python-dmidecode
- https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/08/02/reading-the-smbios-tables-using-delphi/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS

##### Cheatsheets:

[image: Table structure scheme]

[image: Structure table example]

| Offset | Name | Length | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00h | Type | BYTE | Specifies the type of structure. Types 0 through 127 (7Fh) are reserved for and defined by this specification. Types 128 through 256 (80h to FFh) are available for system- and OEM-specific information. |
| 01h | Length | BYTE | Specifies the length of the formatted area of the structure, starting at the Type field. The length of the structure's string-set is not included. |
| 02h | Handle | WORD | Specifies the structure’s handle, a unique 16-bit number in the range 0 to OFFFEh (for version 2.0) or 0 to OFEFFh (for version 2.1 and later). The handle can be used with the Get SMBIOS Structure function to retrieve a specific structure; the handle numbers are not required to be contiguous. For version 2.1 and later, handle values in the range OFFOOh to OFFFFh are reserved for use by this specification !"! If the system configuration changes, a previously assigned handle might no longer exist. However, after a handle has been assigned by the BIOS, the BIOS cannot re-assign that handle number to another structure. |